# I need to arbitrarily prove a set of matrix is an upper triangular matrix.

Tags: matrices

Fix $n$ and let $\mathsf{UT}(n)$ be set of all $n\times n$ upper triangular matrices.
Prove: if $A \in \mathsf{UT}(n)$ and $B\in \mathsf{UT}(n)$ so are $AB$ and $\alpha A$ and $\beta B$ for all $\alpha, \beta$ elements of Real Numbers

I don't understand how i can show that a particular matrix is an element of another larger matrix. I understand that if any matrix is an upper triangular matrix, then if I multiply it by any real number then the result would still be an upper triangular matrix. Are all matrix sub-elements(if this is a thing) of an upper triangular matrix also an upper triangular matrix?

Comment: Welcome to Math.se. Please use MathJax to format mathematics. Regarding the question itself note that the set $\mathsf{UT}(n)$ of upper triangular $n \times n$ matrices is **not** a matrix but a set of matrices. Hence we can say for a matrix $A$ that $A\in \mathsf{UT}(n)$ or $A \notin \mathsf{UT}(n)$...

Comment: The text should be read like this $A \in UT_n, B \in UT_n \implies C \in UT_n$ where $C=AB$. In words: if $A$ and $B$ are upper triangular, so is $AB$. So where is your problem ?

Comment: Thank you!! I am new here ;(( I shall fix my formatting next time sorry for the hinderance.

I got confused regarding A and B being an element of UT(n). I understand now that A and B are upper triangular matrices from the start. However, from the given, Can I assume that the size of A and B is equal?

Comment: Yes by definition of $UT_n$.